# Why does /dev/urandom not block?

Tags: linux, entropy

I know that `/dev/random` **blocks** to wait for more entropy comes in, but why does `/dev/urandom` not block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because its purpose is not to block. That's literally what distinguishes it from `/dev/random`. So you don't have to worry about blocking, but the bits you get from it may not be quite as random as those from `/dev/random`.

According to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/4/urandom):

> If there is not sufficient entropy in the entropy pool, the returned
> values from `/dev/urandom` are theoretically vulnerable to a
> cryptographic attack on the algorithms used by the driver.

The man page adds:

> Knowledge of how to do this is not available in the current
> unclassified literature, but it is theoretically possible that such an
> attack may exist.